# How to add borde r to rmarkdown chunk to create html output in r

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

is there a way I can add a border to markdown chunk HTML output in r

this would enable me to separate the HTML output report

currently, the HTML output report is like the image below
this is how the HTML output looks like

[image]

but I want something like a frame or border that differentiate per chunk output or shows that all the tables and charts are all in the same presentation

I want it to look like something like this
[image]

Comment: did you try `+theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 3))` of your ggplot? that will do a border, that will produce you that output in rmarkdown.

Comment: not necessary the ggplot but the whole chunk output in rmarkdwon

Comment: You should post a sample document that people can work on as a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: see the same and exactly what I want what I shared or be specific what do you want?